# What's the limit on the no. of partitions I can have?

Tags: linux, partition

I would like to know how many `Primary` and `Extended Partitions` I can create on a x86_64 PC with Linux running on it?

---

**Update**  :
If there is a limit to the number of partitions, why is that the limit?

Comment: Some more discussion of where the limits come from: http://contextswitching.tumblr.com/post/154159186893/maximum-partitions-on-linux

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The limitation is due to the original BIOS design. At that time, people weren't thinking more than four different OSes would be installed on a single disk. There was also a misunderstanding of the standard by OS implementors, notably Microsoft and Linux which erroneously map file systems with (primary) partitions instead of subdividing their own partition in slices like BSD and Solaris which was the original intended goal.

The maximum number of logical partitions is unlimited by the standard but the number of reachable ones depends on the OS. Windows is limited by the number of letters in the alphabet, Linux used to have 63 slots with the IDE driver (hda1 to hda63) but modern releases standardize on the sd drivers which supports by default 15 slots (sda1 to sda15). By some tuning, this limit can be overcome but might confuse tools (see  http://www.justlinux.com/forum/showthread.php?t=152404 )

In any case, this is becoming history with EFI/GPT. Recent Linuxes support GPT with which you can have 128 partitions by default. To fully use large disks (2TB and more) you'll need GPT anyway.

Comment: I believe you only need GPT if the partition /boot is on is greater than 2TB.  / should be able to be larger than 2TB since the kernel mounts it rather than the bootloader.

Comment: How would the non /boot partitions be defined ?

Comment: __There was also a misunderstanding of the standard by OS implementors, notably Microsoft and Linux which erroneously map file systems with (primary) partitions instead of subdividing their own partition in slices like BSD and Solaris which was the original intended goal.__ I dint understand this. Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @Sen: the original goal was that each OS would use a single partition, and if an OS wanted more than one filesystem, it would divide the partition into slices. But Linux (originally) and Windows use separate partitions for each filesystem.

Comment: _"Linux used to have 63 slots with the IDE driver (hda1 to hda63) but modern releases standardize on the sd drivers which supports by default 15 slots (sda1 to sda15). By some tuning, this limit can be overcome but might confuse tools"_ is this still true, even for MBR based partitions?

Answer (score 3):

Sen, in response to @jlliagre, it should be noted that some operating systems will create a single partition, but essentially create sub-partitions within that space.

It is analogous, but not equal, to doing:

```
 parted rm 1 /dev/sda
 ...
 parted rm 7 /dev/sda
 parted mkpart primary $start $end /dev/sda
 parted mkpart primary $start1 $end1 /dev/sda1
```

You could then use kpartx to access these sub-partitions:

```
 kpartx -a /dev/sda1
```

The sub-partition(s) would appear as:

```
 /dev/sda1p1
```

Of course, this isn't how FreeBSD and similar systems do their slicing, exactly, but it is essentially the same thing.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't wrote nobody followed the intended goal, just that two mainstream OSes didn't, at least originally. The IBM PC-AT introduced the extended partition standard which was limiting the damage. Modern OSes like those using volume managers or even better, ZFS, no more demand a one to one relationship between file systems and partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Partitions are totally depended upon Disk type format.
If we use MBR Disk type in Linux then we can create 4 total partitions like:

1. All four partitions are Primary only.
2. Three partitions are primary and remaining 1 is extended.

If we consider above 2 steps then under Extended partition we can create almost 65536 new logical partitions and use them but this logical partitions we can use have some limit and it depends upon OS to OS.

**How many partitions we can create under Extended partitions?**
Answer: Suppose you created the last partition in MBR as an extended partition and under it, we create a 1GB partition as a logical partition.

Their structure as follows:

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l /dev/sdb 

Disk /dev/sdb: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk label type: dos 
Disk identifier: 0x4bc89c19 

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  
/dev/sdb1            2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux  
/dev/sdb2         2099200     2293759       97280   83  Linux  
/dev/sdb3         2293760     2488319       97280   83  Linux   
/dev/sdb4         2488320    41943039    19727360    5  Extended < br/>

[root@localhost ~]# fdisk  /dev/sdb 
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2). 

Changes will remain in memory only until you decide to write them. 

Be careful before using the write command. 

Command (m for help): n    
All primary partitions are in use    
Adding logical partition 5    
First sector (2490368-41943039, default 2490368):    
Using default value 2490368   
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (2490368-41943039, default 41943039): +1G   
Partition 5 of type Linux and of size 1 GiB is set  

Command (m for help): p   

Disk /dev/sdb: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors  
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disk label type: dos  
Disk identifier: 0x4bc89c19  

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  
/dev/sdb1            2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux  
/dev/sdb2         2099200     2293759       97280   83  Linux  <
/dev/sdb3         2293760     2488319       97280   83  Linux  
/dev/sdb4         2488320    41943039    19727360    5  Extended  
/dev/sdb5         2490368     4587519     1048576   83  Linux
```

Now, After create a 1GB logical partition above we can calculate the total number of logical partition under the extended partition.We know MBR supports 1 Sector space =512 bytes

Difference between `/dev/sdb5` and `/dev/sdb4` Starting Sector Values has follows 2490368-2488320=2048. 2048 is the difference value which is a Reserved Space in Extended Partition to store the information of logical partitions under it. If we multiply 2048 with 512 bytes then total bytes present in Extended partitions to support Logical partitions i.e. 2048*512=1048576 bytes

In MBR, the total size of 64 bytes is used to store the partition information in the partition table. It means partition table stores each partition information in it which has each partition size of 16 bytes. Each partition can use the 16 bytes of space, so according to it, the total of 4 partitions are provided in MBR including extended. If we see the last partition size which is extended partition then they use 16 bytes of space.

It means if we divide the 1048576 bytes to 16 we get a total number of logical partition under extended partition i.e. 1048576/16=65536(Maximum Logical Partition).

We can use maximum 65536 total logical partitions under it. But the use of this partition depends upon OS to OS. In Linux, MBR uses maximum 60 logical partitions under the extended partition.

So total number of partitions we can create under MBR is 3(primary),1(Extended),60(Logical)=64
But only primary and logical partitions are used to feed the Linux data not extended partitions so it means only 63 partitions are useful to feed the data into the partitions.

**How we can say only 60 maximum partitions are created under MBR and not more than that?**

Just create the logical partitions as much as you can and when you create your 60th logical partition, the system shows this message

```
Command (m for help): n
All primary partitions are in use
Adding logical partition 60
First sector (23013477-41943039, default 23031808): 
Using default value 23031808
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G} (23031808-24035327, default 24035327): +100

Partition 60 of type Linux and of size 50.5 KiB is set

Command (m for help): n
The maximum number of partitions has been created
```

Answer (score 0):

4 primary partitions or alternatively 3 primary partitions and an extended partition.

The extended partition can be subdivided into multiple logical partitions.

Comment: Do you how many logical partitions that would be?

Comment: @Johan: The format doesn't impose any limitation, but most OSes do have one. See [jlliagre's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5730/whats-the-limit-on-the-no-of-partitions-i-can-have/5734#5734).

Answer (score 0):

In a hard disk we can create 4 primary partitions or alternatively 3 primary partitions and an extended partition.
The primary+extended partition can be divided into 63 logical partitions